# Does regenerative cooling reduce specific impulse?

Tags: rockets, engine-design

Specific impulse of exhaust velocity depends on the temperature in the combustion chamber. Won't regenerative cooling lower the chamber temperature, causing the exhaust velocity to decrease?

Comment: The chamber temperature close to the walls is lower, but at the center of the chamber there is very little influence. But without cooling, a chamber for LOX and LH2 would survive only some seconds.

Answer (score 3):

In a regeneratively cooled engine the heat extracted from the chamber and/or nozzle walls is absorbed by the fuel, which is later burned.  So compared to e.g. an ablatively cooled engine, the reactants start combustion at a higher temperature and therefore finish combustion at a higher temperature, with more total energy available for conversion to velocity. Therefore regenerative cooling actually increases Isp compared to other cooling methods, by recapturing some of the energy that would otherwise be lost (radiated or ablated away) and returning it to where it is wanted.

Comment: Then as for liquid hydrogen & oxygen use on the space shuttle, won't there be a lot of losses in specific impulse compared to using them at room temperature? I know we need to cool them to sufficiently low temperature for storage but I feel like there's a lot of loss

Comment: Yes, a little loss, but vastly less than the disastrous impact on system performance that you'd take if you tried to make the tanks strong and large enough to contain LH2/LOX at room temperature.

Comment: Why don't we heat up the fuel before injection? This will certainly increase the specific impulse. Or is it not possible because of the rocket design?

Comment: We do, and it's called a regeneratively cooled engine.....

Comment: (if you meant in addition to that, where are you going to get the heat?)

Comment: See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Staged_combustion_cycle

Comment: I was thinking a heating element powered by a battery but I guess the engineers must have figured out that the increased weight outweigh the heating effect

Comment: @newbie125 I think you underestimate the amount of thermal mass represented by the fuel and oxidizer.  Without even doing the math, I'd wager that using batteries to preheat the reactants isn't possible at all in any significant way.

Comment: Batteries are much less mass-efficient at storing energy than the chemical propellants, and they're dead weight after they're empty, so there's no way that would be a good tradeoff.

Comment: What would the mass of batteries be to heat up 230,000 lb of cryogenic lh2? I'd say that idea is a non starter.

Comment: @pericynthion: Liquifying hydrogen and oxygen by pressure only at room temperature is not possible anyway. Above the critical point of 32.9 K for hydrogen and 154,5 K for oxygen liquefaction is impossible. There is no LH2 or LOX at room temperature.

Comment: @Uwe yeah, I should have omitted the "L"

Comment: The heat removed from walls of the combustion chamber is partially recovered, but not all energy needed for cooling may be recovered. The gas turbine and the turbo pumps loose some energy and the flow of the coolant thru the channels causes an energy loss too.